# Expensive Data Acquisition -- Gap finding in dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset

I am building a classification model with multiple labels. Data Acquisition is a problem because it is laborious and expensive. Therefore, I am trying to find methods to analyze the current dataset vis-a-vis the classification performance and identify those specific classes for which more data acquisition would help.

What are the methodologies in this regard? I have tried to look at Active learning literature, but have not had much confidence.

Comment: i doubt you'll find anything on this subject for this depends entirely on the objective of the classification

Comment: Each datapoint has 401D features and the objective of classification is to assign correct labels.